# changing index column with another column in R

Tags: r

How do I change the index column (1,5,6,...) with the "ID" column in the data frame below[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a data.frame, and you want to replace the rownames with ID (and values for ID are unique):

```
rownames(data.df) <- data.df$ID
```

Or maybe you meant vice versa (replacing the ID column with the index column):

```
data.df$ID <- rownames(data.df)
```